# correlating text files to numbers

Tags: python

Hello and thanks for looking :)

I am relatively new to coding but have come to enjoy figuring out as much as I can for myself.  I've come to a situation where I dont know where to proceed.

Basically I am trying to make an upgrade procedure for a device.  I have a text file with the names of versions of software to upgrade to on different lines of the text file already.

What I want to do is print a number, from 1 to wherever the file ends, and have that number be stored in a variable that will call the associated version number it was printed next to.

I have created something that RESEMBLES what I'm talking about, but there is no way (at least I dont think) to associate the count variable to the version printed after it.

```
    def modify_ftp(self):
        with open('/tmp/ftp', 'r') as f:
            data = f.read().splitlines()
            count = 0
            for line in data:
                if line.endswith('.bin'):
                    count = count + 1
                    print ("> " + str(count) + " <",  line)
            selection = raw_input("\tSelect a version of code to upgrade/downgrade to")
        os.remove('/tmp/ftp')
```

produces output similar to

```
('> 1 <', 'a.bin')
('> 2 <', 'b.bin')
('> 3 <', 'c.bin')
('> 4 <', 'd.bin')
('> 5 <', 'e.bin')
('> 6 <', 'f.bin')
('> 7 <', 'g.bin')
('> 8 <', 'h.bin')
```

To start out, I'll say that I'm sure there is a better way to do this in itself (even in its non functional method of programming).  I'd like to, on the next line, request input of a choice, and that choice would be tied to the relevant *.bin file for later processing in the program.  I am sorry if I was unclear in any way.  Thank you so very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use an array to store the values:

```
    def modify_ftp(self):
    with open('/tmp/ftp', 'r') as f:
        data = f.read().splitlines()
        count = 0
        arr = []
        for line in data:
            if line.endswith('.bin'):
                count = count + 1

                arr.append(line)
                print ("> " + str(count) + " <",  line)
        selection = raw_input("\tSelect (i.e. 1, 2... 15) a version of code to upgrade/downgrade to: ")
```

I can then reference the version value with a number stored in "selection"

```
print (arr[int(selection) - 1])
os.remove('/tmp/ftp')
```

Answer (score 1):

The lines are already stored in a list (data), so you should be able to access line number by just doing

```
runFile = data[selection - 1]
```

We do `selection - 1` to index it properly since your numbering system is indexed starting at 1, whereas lists index starting at 0

Note: This is assuming you wanted sequential numbers for your versions. If you wanted a more abstract approach, I would explore dictionarys [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) and learn how to associate data in pairs.

It really depends on how you plan on choosing the numbers that are associative. Might be best to place that kind of data within the file since it seems as though it will be hardcoded into the program anyway.

Comment: I've tried this a few times, but I'm not able to perform this assignment as the two terms seem unrelated.  My attempts only return a number of the count - 1 .  Thanks for your help though.